# Compiling FoldList implementation for RK4

Tags: differential-equations, compile

**Original**

I'm looking to write an integrator for a function of two variables. Here is my implementation for the RK4 update rule using FoldList.

```
RK4Update[fx_, x_, prms_, numsteps_] :=
Block[{},

1.0/(6.0 numsteps)
Dot[{1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0},
 Rest[
  FoldList[
   fx @@ {x + #1 #2, prms} &,
   x,
   Divide[{0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0}, 1.0 numsteps]
   ]
  ]
 ]

];
```

This function evaluates correctly when given `g` (below) and numerical list arguments for `x` and `prms`. I'm attempting to compile to gain speed:

```
Compile[
{{sts, _Real, 1}, {pms, _Real, 1}, {tsteps, _Real}},
Evaluate[RK4Update[g, sts, pms, tsteps]],
CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]
```

Here `g` is an already compiled function of two vector arguments. The compiler is unhappy, returning errors of the form:

```
Part::partd: Part specification pms[[2]] is longer than depth of object. 
Part specification pms[[1]] is longer than depth of object
Part::partw: "Part 3 of 0. +sts does not exist"
```

and further errors from the attempted evaluation of `g`. I'm not sure if there is any way to proceed here. Is there a simple fix? Or is an overhaul needed?

If it's of any help, a sample function `g` is polynomial in elements of its arguments

```
(#2[[2]] #1[[3]] (1- #1[[1]])+ #1[[2]]^2(1 - #1[[1]])
+ #1[[1]](2 - #1[[1]]))/#2[[1]]
```

Curiously, `CompilePrint` returns what appears to be a fully compiled code. However, this code (perhaps unsurprisingly) does not produce the correct result.

**Update**

The function `RK4Update` can be condensed to

```
RK4Update[fx_, x_, prms_,numsteps_] :=
  1.0/(6.0 numsteps)
  Dot[{1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0},
   FoldList[
    fx[x + #1 #2, prms] &,
    fx[x, prms],
    Divide[{0.5, 0.5, 1.0}, 1.0 numsteps]
   ]
  ]
```

The following compilation command outputs several errors, but returns a successfully compiled function. A `Quiet` prefix suppresses display of these errors:

```
 cf= Quiet@Compile[
 {{st, _Real, 1}, {pm, _Real, 1}, {tstep, _Real}},
 Evaluate[RK4Update[h, st, pm, tstep]],
 CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}]
```

where, importantly, `h[x,y] = {g1[x,y],g2[x,y],g3[x,y]}` with `x,y` each a numeric list and `g_i` a set of compiled functions. In the original question, `g` in the `FoldList` call returns a single number, whereas `x` is a triplet. A function in `FoldList` must output a quantity with the same dimension as its argument.

For some reason, `cf` outputs a `3x3` matrix whose diagonal is the desired result. My current working (yet unsatisfactorily ad hoc) solution is given by calling
`Diagonal[cf[Range[3],Range[2]]`

Comment: Does `RK4Update` work when you do not compile it?

Comment: Sorry, wrong `g`. The `g` posted in the question evaluates `RK4Update[g, 0.001 Range[3], 0.1 Range[2], 10.]`
to `0.008720484`

Comment: You might be interested in looking at Roman Maeder's implementation of a Runge-Kutta integrator in his *Programming in Mathematica*. The implementation there uses replacement rules, however, so it can't be compiled.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, GWII. I've discovered the problem with my code and will update the post.

Comment: @sampson - If you have solved the problem, you should write your own answer to this question (and mark it as accepted) rather than updating your question.

Comment: @Myridium, I have updated with a workaround, but the updated post still has a question, namely why a Diagonal[] wrapper is required to produce the desired output

Comment: @sampson - I'm finding it difficult to digest your code. Can you describe the desired inputs and outputs of `fx`, and whether `x` and `prms` are supposed to be vectors? Which variables are being integrated, and with respect to which parameterising variable?

Comment: x and y are vectors of real numbers, not necessarily of the same dimension. fx takes (x,y) to x' which is an element of the space space as x, and is the variable being integrated. prms specifies other parameters in the function fx which are constant throughout integration.

e.g. `fx[{x1,x2,x3},{p1,p2}] --> {x1',x2',x3'}`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the use of the `Evaluate` function inside the `Compile` function. The `Evaluate` function requires that `RK4Update`, and therefore `g`, be passed the correct form of the `x` and `pms` parameters. The pure function definition of `g` provided dictates that these should be a lists of length at least three and at least two, respectively.

However, within the scope of the `Compile` function `RK4Update`, and therefore `g`, are passed undefined variables `sts` and `pms`, which have length `0`. When `RK4Update` is evaluated in this context, you see the `Part` specification errors in the original problem.

This simple modification to the code should work (no `Evaluation`):

```
h = Compile[{{sts, _Real, 1}, {pms, _Real, 1}, {tsteps, _Real}}, 
        RK4Update[g, sts, pms, tsteps], 
        CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]
```